# Can we get the BibTeX entry for a post, like Math.SE?

Tags: feature-request

So, I would like to start this topic to vote (and make available) the BibTeX entry for a post in the *Mathematica* SE community.

It seems to be of general interest to have the possibility to cite the authors of codes developed and posted in this community. I believe this is the best way to avoid plagiarism and recognize the effort of those contributors.

Comment: I've pinged the SE folks about this.

Comment: I'll change my username to "Mr. belisarius" ASAP. (or perhaps I'll wait to see "Mr. Toad" around)

Comment: Is this really a common enough use case to ask for integration into the site?  Most posts are not really cite-worthy, at least in an academic setting.

Comment: @Szabolcs I'll give you an example: my post about the Helio Chart for canonical correlation analysis resulted in a great way to display the relationship between two sets of variables.  So I really **need** to use the chart. So what should I do? Simply put the chart in my paper? Instead of that I prefer to put the code as an appendix **citing** the original source... So in my opinion it should be allowed to avoid, as said, plagiarism.

Comment: Of course it's allowed to cite posts :-)  I was just wondering if this is a common enough thing that the site should have special support to generate bibtex for it (which can be easily  written by hand anyway)

Comment: Can you add some examples of where this would've come in handy to the post here?